# Unable to save data in gatsby graphql layer while creating source plugin

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to fetch all the videos of a youtube channel grouped by playlist. So first i am fetching all the playlists and then again fetching the corresponding videos.

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const queryString = require("query-string")

module.exports.sourceNodes = async (
  { actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest },
  configOptions
) => {
  const { createNode } = actions

  // Gatsby adds a configOption that's not needed for this plugin, delete it
  delete configOptions.plugins

  // plugin code goes here...
  console.log("Testing my plugin", configOptions)

  // Convert the options object into a query string
  const apiOptions = queryString.stringify(configOptions)
  const apiUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?${apiOptions}`

  // Helper function that processes a content to match Gatsby's node structure
  const processContent = content => {
    const nodeId = createNodeId(`youtube--${content.id}`)
    const nodeContent = JSON.stringify(content)
    const nodeData = Object.assign({}, content, {
      id: nodeId,
      parent: null,
      children: [],
      internal: {
        type: `tubeVideo`,
        content: nodeContent,
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(content)
      }
    })
    return nodeData
  }

  return fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.items.forEach(item => {
        console.log("item", item.id)
        //fetch videos of the playlist
        let playlistApiOption = queryString.stringify({
          part: "snippet,contentDetails",
          key: "AIzaSyDPdlc3ctJ7yodRZE_GfbngNBEYbdcyys8",
          playlistId: item.id,
          fields: "items(id,snippet(title,description,thumbnails),contentDetails)"
        })
        let playlistApiUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?${playlistApiOption}`
        fetch(playlistApiUrl)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            data.items.forEach(video => {
              console.log("videos", video)
              // Process the video data to match the structure of a Gatsby node
              const nodeData = processContent(video)
              //  console.log(nodeData)
              // Use Gatsby's createNode helper to create a node from the node data
              createNode(nodeData)
            })
          })
      })
    })
}
```

Here Nodes are getting created for individual videos. But can't query this nodes from graphql store. ie. datas are not getting saved in graphql store

Comment: Hi there, how do you know the graphql store doesn't have the nodes? Did you try querying for `tubeVideo` or `allTubeVideo` in graphiQL (localhost:8000/___graphql)?

Comment: @DerekNguyen. Yes. I cheked in graphiql and its not there. But nodes are created, i checked using onCreateNode.

Answer (score 0):

edit: Wait, I just realize it's inside a loop. Your `sourceNodes` is not waiting for the fetch inside your loop to resolve. In this case, you'd have to use something like `Promise.all` to resolve each item in the loop. Code's updated to reflect that.

```
  return fetch(apiUrl)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      return Promise.all(
        data.items.map(item => {
          /* etc. */
          return fetch(playlistApiUrl)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
              data.items.forEach(video => {
                /* etc. */
                createNode(nodeData)
              })
            })
        )
      })
    })
```

Check out `async/await` syntax, it might make finding these type of issue easier.